# How do I choose the minimum date if it exists and the maximum date if it doesn't?

Tags: sql-server

For example,
I want

```
  import_date =  DATEADD(DAY, -7, getdate())
```

(7 days prior to today) if it does exist, and if it doesn't exist I want

```
    import_date = DATEADD(DAY, -6, getdate())
```

which is 6 days prior to today. If both exist I want 7 days prior to today and if neither exist I want the latest date there is.

Here is an example of the columns:

hotel ¦ segment ¦ import_date ¦ revenue ¦  arrival date ¦

---

the date in question is the **import_date**

Comment: Hint: `IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: `coalesce` might work here too

Comment: `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY import_date ASC` ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin `TOP 1` won't work here, will return just one row.

Comment: So really the 7 days or 6 days don't really matter. What you really want is the oldest row that is within the last 7 days right?

Comment: Are you trying to get a single row returned or a single row for each hotel (or whatever is group)?

Comment: Add sample data and desired result to your question please.

Comment: @SeanLange I want a single row for each hotel

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which show you how:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable ( import_date DATE);

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES
('2017-10-24'),
('2017-10-25'),
('2017-10-26'),
('2017-10-27'),
('2017-10-28');
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM YourTable WHERE import_date =  CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, getdate()) AS DATE)))
       SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE import_date = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -6, getdate()) AS DATE)
           ELSE
                   SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE import_date =  CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, getdate()) AS DATE);
```

Results:

```
+---------------------+
|     import_date     |
+---------------------+
| 26.10.2017 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You have date math in here against getdate() which does NOT return a date. Your exists query is not converting that to a date.

Comment: Thanks @Sami how do I do this for each hotel?

Comment: @Sami how do i do this for each hotel?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sparse on details but you can use this to get the oldest row for each hotel where the row was imported within the last 7 days.

```
select *
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by hotel order by import_date desc)
    from YourTable
    where import_date >= dateadd(day, -7, convert(date, getdate()))
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```